# Is there a pack/unpack version of this?

Tags: php

I have this loop:

```
$encoded = '';
while ($number) {
  $encoded = chr($number & 0xFF) . $encoded;
  $number = $number >> 8;
}
return $encoded;
```

and I was wondering whether there's an equivalent `pack` or `unpack` for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're encoding this as a big-endian representation (meaning most significant byte first), but with a variable width.

So to get the bytes:

```
pack("N", $number)
```

You can also use 64 bit with `J`.

But you also need to trim off leading null bytes (for variable width):

```
ltrim(pack("N", $number), chr(0))
```

Comment: Note that 64 bit support requires PHP 5.6.3.